# Show that $\{t_1v_1, t_2v_2\}$ is an orthogonal set?

Tags: inner-products, orthogonality

> Let {$\vec v$<sub>1</sub> $\vec v$<sub>2</sub>} be an orthogonal set of vectors in R<sup>n</sup>, and let t<sub>1</sub>, t<sub>2</sub> be ∈ R.
> Show that {t<sub>1</sub>$\vec v$<sub>1</sub>, t<sub>2</sub>$\vec v$<sub>2</sub>} is an orthogonal set.

I know that i probably have to use this property
$$(c\vec u)⋅\vec v = c (\vec u ⋅ \vec v) = u⋅(c\vec v).$$

I know that multiplying by different scalars will still give me an orthogonal set.

I don't know how to actually prove it equal to zero. Do i just use simply algebra to prove this by setting one side equal to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{v_1, v_2\}$ be an orthogonal set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Then $\langle v_1 , v_2\rangle = 0$.

Claim :  $\{t_1 v_1,t_2 v_2\}$ is also an orthogonal set of vectors for any $t_1 , t_2 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Indeed, we have that

$\langle t_1 v_1,t_2 v_2\rangle = t_1 t_2 \langle v_1, v_2\rangle=0$

Comment: Alright, I guess I was just overthinking the question. Thanks for taking the time to help.